# how can i monitor the memory usage of each thread of my process in linux?

Tags: linux

In top command, i couldn't find any option. Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this meaningfully, because all threads in a process share the same memory space.

Any memory allocated by one thread is also available to all the others, and you can (for example) `malloc` some memory in thread A then pass a pointer to that memory to thread B. The memory does not "belong" to A or B, but to the process as a whole.

Comment: Yeah..u r right..it belongs to the process..but event that memory allocated from heap will be created by some thread..I think it's possible